# Filter a ng-repeat with values from an array

Tags: angularjs

I have this table with a ng-repeat.

```
ng-repeat="project in projects"
```

I have a property in project, `prj_city`. I'd like to filter this value.

I can do this with:

```
ng-repeat="project in projects | filter={prj_city: <value>}
```

But I want the `<value>` to be an array with multiple cities instead of a string. Is there any easy way to do this or do I have to do this filter manually in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a custom filter in the controller, should be easy enough tho:

```
var filteredCities = ["LosAngelos", "etc.."];

$scope.arrayFilter = function(project) {
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
        if (filteredCities[i] == project.prj_city)
            return true;
    }
    return false
}
```

And the call:

```
ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: arrayFilter"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a filter function on your controller.  Something like:

```
$scope.filteredCities = function(city) {
    return ($scope.userFilteredCities.indexOf(city) !== -1);
};

$scope.userFilteredCities;//List of filtered cities
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function in your controller:

```
// use a map for faster filtering
var acceptedCityMap = {};
angular.forEach(acceptedCities, function(city) {
    // case insensitive search. But you're not forced to
    acceptedCityMap[city.toLowerCase()] = true;
});

$scope.isProjectedAccepted = function(project) {
    // case insensitive search. But you're not forced to
    return acceptedCityMap[project.prj_city.toLowerCase()];
}
```

And then in your view:

```
ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:isProjectAccepted"
```